# How do I expand org sections that only contain properties?

Tags: org-mode

Given the following org-mode text:

```
* Heading
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CATEGORY: demo
  :END:
```

If it's collapsed, I can cycle between these two states:

```
* Heading...
```

and

```
* Heading
  :PROPERTIES:...
```

However, I can't see any way of expanding PROPERTIES whilst point is on `* Heading`. I can only expand PROPERTIES when point is on that line. This is unlike subheadings, which I can expand even when point is on the toplevel heading.

I want visibility cycling to include PROPERTIES. How can I expand PROPERTIES here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`org-show-subtree` is actually doing its job when cycling. It shows the contents of the drawer (like `:PROPERTIES:`). But, `org-cycle-hide-drawers` in `org-cycle-hook` hides the drawers again.

The good thing is that you can customize `org-cycle-hook` and remove `org-cycle-hide-drawers`.

I just cite the customization page for this option here:

```
Org Cycle Hook:
INS DEL org-cycle-hide-archived-subtrees
INS DEL org-cycle-hide-drawers
INS DEL org-cycle-show-empty-lines
INS DEL org-optimize-window-after-visibility-change
INS
    State : STANDARD.
   Hook that is run after ‘org-cycle’ has changed the buffer visibility. Hide
   The function(s) in this hook must accept a single argument which indicates
   the new state that was set by the most recent ‘org-cycle’ command.  The
   argument is a symbol.  After a global state change, it can have the values
   ‘overview’, ‘contents’, or ‘all’.  After a local state change, it can have
   the values ‘folded’, ‘children’, or ‘subtree’.
Groups: Org Cycle
```

Alternatively you could bind another key (e.g., <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>) for showing the full subtree:

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (local-set-key (kbd "C-c s") 'org-show-subtree)))
```

Answer (score 0):

From `org-cycle`s doc string:

```
With a triple C-u prefix argument, show the entire buffer, including any drawers
```

The info docs don't mention any other way to open or close drawers without moving there. If you want more, it's time to write some elisp!